# Text Environments: Vertical and Horizontal

Tags: spacing, formatting, positioning

How does one obtain two text environments in TeX - one vertical, one horizontal, as in the attached image? It would be useful to be able to specify two text environments per page akin to something like this:

```
\vertical{This text appears on the side}

\horizontal{This text appears horizontally}
```

While being able to specify the width available to text appearing vertically and having the horizontal text naturally flow down the page naturally - as if were a document with shortened page width. I tried implementing this with minipage and rotation but was not able to create coherent environments. Is there a 'natural way' of doing this?

[image]

Comment: Will the content only remain on a single page?

Comment: @Werner I was only ever planning on having a single page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried implementing this with minipage and rotation but was not able to create coherent environments.

This should be enough.

[image: mew]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
\begin{minipage}{.7\textheight}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}}
\hfill  
\begin{minipage}[c][.7\textheight][t]{.65\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```